# shell script to extract particular tag info from xml file

Tags: xml, shell, xml-parsing

I want to extract `<InFrame>` tag information data for all respective `<SOUNDCHEK>` tags

Data from all `<Inframe>` tags in file is : -1 0 2 4 7

But I want `<Inframe>` info from `<SOUNDCHEK>` tag only : 2 4 7 [Desired output]

```html
<APP>
    <Name>MainCheck</Name>
    <ActiveField>True</ActiveField>
    <InFrame>-1</InFrame>
    <CAMRECORD>
        <Name>Camera01</Name>
        <ActiveField>True</ActiveField>
        <InFrame>0</InFrame>
    </CAMRECORD>
    <SOUNDCHEK>
        <Name>Sound1.wav</Name>
        <ActiveField>True</ActiveField>
        <InFrame>2</InFrame>
    </SOUNDCHEK>
    <SOUNDCHEK>
        <Name>Sound2.wav</Name>
        <ActiveField>True</ActiveField>
        <InFrame>4</InFrame>
    </SOUNDCHEK>
    <SOUNDCHEK>
        <Name>Sound3.wav</Name>
        <ActiveField>True</ActiveField>
        <InFrame>7</InFrame>
    </SOUNDCHEK>
</APP>
```

Answer (score 1):

With **`xmlstalet`** tool:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//SOUNDCHEK/InFrame" -n input.xml
```

- `//SOUNDCHEK/InFrame` - xpath expression to select all `InFrame` nodes which are children of `SOUNDCHEK` nodes

The output:

```
2
4
7
```

http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139652416

Comment: thanks for the response, would appreciate some solution with standard command or shell script

Comment: @ScriptWriter, xml/html parsers are the only write tools for parsing xml/html data. Any other grep/bash/shell tools should be considered as dirty hacks and fragile approaches

Answer (score 0):

Try using xmllint and select the required data with a xpath.

```
xmllint --xpath '/APP/SOUNDCHECK/InFrame/text()' file.xml
```